# Passing a newline using $_GET string

Tags: php, html

I have to pass a string to a form.
I want to use a mix of $_GET and $_POST in the following way:

```
 <?php $string="bla bla bla".$some_other_string."bla bla".$some_other_string2."\n"; ?>

 <form action="this_page.php?string=<?php echo $string?>" method="post" name="name">

 </form>
```

Please note the `\n` in the string.
When I get the `$_GET("string")` (or `$_REQUEST("string"`), it happens the following: the php parser get the \n as a string. So he put it into the string as I had coded: `\\\n` and it's not the result I want. I want simply a inner `\n` in a php string.

Please can you explain me why this behaviour happens, without complaining that it's not the best way to pass a string (I suppose it isn't, but today I had an issue and I wanted to manage it by passing the string this way)?

Ps: I have to use the `\n` and not the html `<br />` because I have to let php write into a file.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is, but try using `echo urlencode( $string)`, it should fix all your poblems.

Comment: the problem was basically that I wanted to write a string in a file, and I wanted to format it using newlines, and I wanted to pass it using a $_GET in the action url. For some reason, the /n ended up in the string as a two characters /n and not as a  new line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Advice**: You probably should think about putting this into a hidden field

**Answer**: But if you are going to put it into action as a GET parameter, then you need to urlencode the string:

```
<form action="this_page.php?string=<?php echo urlencode($string); ?>" method="post" name="name">
```

That way - any non-alphanumeric characters will be url safe (think about what might happen if $string contained a ? or a # or an = ).

PHP automatically decodes GET parameters when loading them into the $_GET array - so your newline should be preserved at that point.

Comment: the  urlencode function worked; nice, I know to way to do it now.